# How to create a template for a Views row style?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I want to create a template file for a Views row style. I have created a template file for a field as `views-view-fields--menu.tpl.php` and output style file as `views-view--menu.tpl.php`.

How to create a template for a view row style?

Comment: needs to be `views-view-fields--menu.tpl.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Advanced section in your view, there is a theme option in the last row. On clicking it you can get suggestions for possible template files in row style output sub heading. In this the last option is the most specific one.

Also on clicking the row style output heading you can get the code of default row style tpl which is getting called currently, which you can add in your tpl file and override it as per your requirement.